# How to use actix_web::client::Client in Actix-web 4.0

Tags: rust, actix-web, scylla

I use crate scylla that use tokio 1, so i must use crate actix-web 4.0 beta.
Now i have problem that use actix_web::client::Client show error :

```
3 | use actix_web::client::Client;
  |                ^^^^^^ could not find `client` in `actix_web`
```

i want to hit API inside actix handler with this code :

```
pub(crate) async fn proses_mapmatching(data: web::Data<AppState>) -> impl Responder {

    let client = Client::default();

    let res = client.post("http://localhost:8002/trace_route")
        .send()
        .await
        .unwrap()
        .body()
        .await;

    println!("Response: {:?}", res);

    HttpResponse::Ok().body(format!("Hello {:?}", res))
}
```

Any idea to still use actix-web 4 with reqest post insede handler function ?
Thanks

**ANSWER CODE with AWC - Thanks to Mr. @kmdreko**

```
pub(crate) async fn proses_mapmatching(data: web::Data<AppState>) -> impl Responder {

    let mut client = awc::Client::default();
    let response = client.post("http://localhost:8002/trace_route")
        .send_body("Raw body contents")
        .await;

    println!("Response: {:?}", response.unwrap().body().await);

    HttpResponse::Ok().body(format!("Hello {}!", rows.len()))
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is mentioned in the `actix_web` [Changes.md](https://github.com/actix/actix-web/blob/master/CHANGES.md#400-beta5---2021-04-02) for v4.0:

> The `client` mod was removed. Clients should now use `awc` directly.

The `actix_web::client` module has long since largely been a wrapper around the [`awc`](https://crates.io/crates/awc) crate ever since the 1.0 release, but it seems they now want to separate them entirely.

The types from `awc` should be near identical to those exposed in prior `actix_web` releases, however if you're using it with `actix_web:4.0` (currently in beta) then you'll want to use `awc:3.0` (currently in beta) for compatibility.

Answer (score 2):

this is what I used to run the AWC Example

Cargo.toml

```
[dependencies]
openssl = "0.10.38"
actix-web = "4.0.0-beta.12"
awc = { version = "3.0.0-beta.11", features = [ "openssl" ] }
```

main.rs

```
use awc::Client;

#[actix_web::main]
async fn main() {
    let client = Client::new();

    let res = client
         .get("http://www.rust-lang.org")    // <- Create request builder
         .insert_header(("User-Agent", "Actix-web"))
         .send()                             // <- Send http request
         .await;

    println!("Response: {:?}", res);        // <- server http response
}
```

bests!